# Selenium- Read a pdf that opens in New tab without url

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, automation, pdfbox, bufferedinputstream

In our application , we have a scenario where we click on a link and after clicking a new tab opens with a dynamically generated PDF.

The generated `PDF` opens in new tab with `"about:blank"` as the URL.

To verify the content of the PDF i am not able to use below code since there is no specific URL

```
URL TestURL = new URL("url");
BufferedInputStream TestFile = new BufferedInputStream(TestURL.openStream());
PDFParser TestPDF = new PDFParser(TestFile);

TestPDF.parse();
String TestText = new PDFTextStripper().getText(TestPDF.getPDDocument());
```

I don't have option to download the generated PDF as well.

Is there any way we can solve this ??
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You could record your network traffic using a proxy server (like BrowserMob Proxy) and find the response body for your PDF file, which could be fed into your code above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563147/can-selenium-verify-text-inside-a-pdf-loaded-by-the-browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Actions class to select all the content using "CTRL+A" then copy ("CTRL+C") and then paste it somewhere you can extract the text and verify.

Comment: Thank you for your input , now i am trying to implement the same but now i am facing this problem [timeOutException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50664871/seleniumtimed-out-receiving-message-from-renderer-exception-when-switching-to-n)

Comment: Sorry, I was late. I suppose this problem is solved now.

Comment: You are welcome. If you found the answer helpful, please accept the answer.