# how to open pdf file in selenium webdriver c#

Tags: testing, automated-tests

I'm working on automation testing and i want to verify data inside PDF after downloading it i try to open PDF file but no gain but if there another way to open PDF in another tab and verify data ?

[downloaded-PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmJLq.png)

Comment: Can you share the code you have tried?

Comment: I just working on automation testing and verify data on excel successfully but i can't find any code for pdf file !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Selenium verify text inside a PDF loaded by the browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563147/can-selenium-verify-text-inside-a-pdf-loaded-by-the-browser)

Comment: thanks i will check